# Swift JSON error: Thread 4: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to getting data from APIs and displaying them on the app.  I have made a GET API web-service using NODE.JS connecting to an MSSQL Server DB, whose response I have posted below:

> {"recordsets":[[{"USERCODE":10000,"USERNAME":"ADMIN","USERFIRSTNAME":"Administrator","USERLASTNAME":"","USERTYPE":0},{"USERCODE":10001,"USERNAME":"nmahamad","USERFIRSTNAME":"Nooh","USERLASTNAME":"Ahamad","USERTYPE":0}]],"recordset":[{"USERCODE":10000,"USERNAME":"ADMIN","USERFIRSTNAME":"Administrator","USERLASTNAME":"","USERTYPE":0},{"USERCODE":10001,"USERNAME":"nmahamad","USERFIRSTNAME":"Nooh","USERLASTNAME":"Ahamad","USERTYPE":0}],"output":{},"rowsAffected":[2]}

My code is mostly a patchwork of code from YouTube and StackOverflow itself. I regularly visit the site looking for similar errors, whose suggestions I have implemented to the code.

```
class HomeModel: NSObject {

    var delegate: HomeModelDelegate?

    func getUsers() {

        //Hit the web service url
        let serviceUrl = "http://localhost:12345/api/GETUsers"

        //Download JSON data
        let url = URL(string: serviceUrl)

        if let url = url {

            //Create a url session
            let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
            let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
                if error == nil {
                    //Data successfully loaded and call the parseJson function on the data
                    self.parseJson(data: data!)
                }
                else {
                    //Some error occurred
                    print("Some error occurred")
                }
            }
            task.resume()
        }
        //Notify the viewcontroller and pass the data back
    }

    func parseJson(data: Data) {
        var usrArray = [User]()
        var jsonArray : Array<AnyObject> = []
        //Parse the data into User struct
        do {
            let tmp : AnyObject! = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as AnyObject
            if let arr = tmp as? Array<AnyObject> {
                jsonArray = arr
            } else {
                jsonArray = tmp["recordsets"] as! Array<AnyObject>
            }
            //Parse the data into JSON Object
            //Loop through each result in the JSON array
            for jsonArr in jsonArray {
                for jsonResult in jsonArr as! [AnyObject] {
                    //Caste JSON result as a dictionary
                    let jsonDict = jsonResult as! [String:Any]
                    //Create new User and set its properties
                    let usr = User(mUsrCode: jsonDict["USERCODE"]! as! String, mUsrNm: jsonDict["USERNAME"]! as! String, mUsrFNm: jsonDict["USERFIRSTNAME"]! as! String, mUserLNm: jsonDict["USERLASTNAME"]! as! String, mUsrType: jsonDict["USERTYPE"]! as! Int)
                    //Add the user to the array
                    usrArray.append(usr)
                }
            }
            //Pass the data array back to the delegate
            delegate?.usersDownloaded(users: usrArray)
        }
        catch{
            //Some error occurred
            print("Some error occurred")
        }
    }
}
```

I have made incremental changes for various errors referring to various sources until I reached a point where the app just crashed with no error message in the console... The following message was then displayed at this line, "let jsonDict = jsonResult as! [String:String]";

> Thread 4: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

Comment: Your dictionary contains both string and int values so you need to change your cast to `[String: Any]`. Maybe it would be a good idea to let `User` implement `Decodable`, you could really get rid of a lot of code then

Comment: And change your error handling from printing a hardcoded string to printing the actual error, `print(error)`

Comment: Thanks a ton..... however this is what i get next, `error: expected member name or constructor call after type name` at the jsondict declaration

Comment: Could you show how that line you get an error on looks like, `let jsonDict ...`?

Comment: //Caste JSON result as a dictionary.              
                    `let jsonDict = jsonResult as! [String:Any]`          
                    //Create new User and set its properties
                    `let usr = User(mUsrCode: jsonDict["USERCODE"]! as! String, mUsrNm: jsonDict["USERNAME"]! as! String, mUsrFNm: jsonDict["USERFIRSTNAME"]! as! String, mUserLNm: jsonDict["USERLASTNAME"]! as! String, mUsrType: jsonDict["USERTYPE"]! as! Int)
`

Comment: Well you can't cast an int as a string, compare your code with your Json message. Your code would probably be easier to debug if you create intermediate local variables, like `let userCode = jsonDict["USERCODE"]!` before calling the constructor